# PHP MySql loop through all child ID's

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySql database which contains information about saved file and folder structures.

There is table called "Folder" which contains its "ID", "Name" and "ParentID".

Basically what I need to do is loop through all child folders and child folder's child folder and gather their ID's until there is no more child folders left.

Currently i have PHP script which contains function called `GetChilds($parentId)`.
Function runs SQL-query which gathers all Folder ID's where ParentID is `$parentID`. After that there is `foreach` loop calling same function again with found ID's.

This works as expected but its extremely slow and what I have read, it is not recommended to put queries inside loops in PHP.

So what I am looking for is alternative way to perform same functionality in more efficient way using either SQL-script or PHP.

EDIT:

Here is my code:

```
private function FetchData($query, $query_params, $dbConnection)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($query); 

        if(count($query_params) > 0)
            $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        else
            $stmt->execute();

            return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        //Handle error
    }
}

private function GetChilds($parentId, $connection)
{
    $childFolders = $this->FetchData("select idFolder from Folder where ParentId = :parentId", array(":parentId" => $parentId), $connection);

    //Save ID's

    foreach($childFolders as $child)
    { 
        $this->GetChilds($child['idFolder'], $connection);
    }
}
```

Comment: please show us your code!

Comment: I'm not saying this post should be downvoted, but not a lick of code has been shown and this post was upvoted. What?

Comment: In the past I've solved a similar problem by having a `path` field that is stored on each entry, for example file foo.jpg within folder test would have path `test/foo.jpg`. Queries like your description are recursive but with a path it becomes trivial. For all subfolders and files of folder `test`: `WHERE path LIKE 'test/%' ORDER BY path ASC`

Comment: Updated code without irrelevant parts.

Comment: why not use a stored procedure

Comment: make sure you have your database indexed, also what is `extremely slow` 1s ? 60s? how many records do you have in this table?

Comment: @cmorrissey It takes around 5-8 seconds to do that operation with less than 30 records in table. If i am not wrong, php open and closes connection with every single query? My database server is located far away from my web server and if it does like that with connection, then it is pretty obvious that multiple queries takes so much time. Thats why i need different solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, one alternative (among many others) is to save your bulk query into an array. Then you can manipulate it as much as you want. 
It's a lot faster.

Comment: Problem is: he doesn't know which parent_id's he'll have to use the query with before fetching the first result from the database. Perhaps a good alternative would be using a prepared statement, but I doubt it would enhance your performance enough 'cause the highest amount of time may be in connecting to the database server instead of the query running itself.

Comment: Maybe if he shows a piece of code, it would be clearer for all